# Connection to mongodb on travis refused

Tags: mongodb, docker, travis-ci

I'm trying to setup mongo on Travis to be used for my integration tests. My travis configuration that initializes mongodb is:

```
env:
  global:
    - MONGODB_URI: mongodb://fillrx_test:test@127.0.0.1:27017/fillrx_test_db
before_install:
  - sleep 15
  - mongo fillrx_test_db --eval 'db.createUser({user:"fillrx_test", pwd:"test",roles:["readWrite"]});'
  - docker build -t jeremycod/api-test -f ./server/Dockerfile.dev ./server

script:
  - docker run --env MONGODB_URI -e CI=true jeremycod/api-test npm test
```

However, this fails on Travis with the connection refused error:

```
      1) Create address endpoint /api/v1/address/user/userId

       "before all" hook: connectToTestDB for "Create address with correct input":

       MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)  {

            name: 'MongoNetworkError'

       }]
```

UPDATE:

Solution to this problem is to run docker container with "--network host", e.g.

```
- docker run --network host --env MONGODB_URI -e CI=true jeremycod/api-test npm test

This approach binds docker container directly to the Docker host’s network, so it's available from docker container at url:

mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo_db_name
```

Comment: You need to start the server.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've missed to add mongodb to the list of services and it was not available. However, after adding mongodb as a service, it doesn't fail from the travis script, but it fails later during the tests that I'm running.

Comment: I'm guessing this might be related to the fact that I'm running tests inside of the docker container.